# TagLostException IsoDep Android Java card

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu

I'm working with a Java card using Android IsoDep. I have already set the timeout to 50000 milliseconds. I also calculated the duration the NFC connection was opened and it was just over 6 seconds.
I put the card on my table and put my phone on top of it and I didn't touch either through the process so there is no chance the card could be removed physically.

Any idea why this is happening?

My code:

```
try {
    if (nfc.isConnected()) {
        DLog.w(TAG, "exchange() - connected");

        byte[] resp = nfc.transceive(apdu);

        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
        close();
    }
} catch (TagLostException e) {
    DLog.e(TAG, "card was removed", e);
    close();
    // ...
}
catch (IOException e) {
    close();
    // ...
}
```

The exception:

```
01-08 09:54:54.721: E/IsoDepSecureHandler(11221): android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.
01-08 09:54:54.721: E/IsoDepSecureHandler(11221):   at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:48)
01-08 09:54:54.721: E/IsoDepSecureHandler(11221):   at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
01-08 09:54:54.721: E/IsoDepSecureHandler(11221):   at android.nfc.tech.IsoDep.transceive(IsoDep.java:172)
```

The particular command that it failed to execute is `80460000400000271020363630303030303030353138323133303134333666383639383063022b100141000100000000000000000036364ed930284231adbc6c525e9f0abd`

However, the same command was executed just fine when I use a contactless reader that connect to my phone. Note that the command can only executed as long as I don't repeat the process and generate new security parameters (some other APDU commands were sent to the card prior to this one). Once new the security parameters are generated, the above command does not work anymore; therefore, `6982` will be returned.

tbellenger suggested adding `00` to the end of the command but that doesn't work, even with the smartcard reader as `6985` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '00' to the end of your APDU. This is sometimes required. Don't modify 'LC' from '40' - just add the zero byte. I think this is required in T=CL or T=1.

Comment: Thanks @tbellenger, adding `00` caused response to be `6985`

Comment: 6985 means something like security conditions not verified or some such thing. Was that what you were expecting?

Comment: No, `6982` is expected. I know this by sending the command through the smartcard reader, instead of the phone

Comment: What applet are you communicating with? Very strange to get a different response than what you get through the smartcard reader...

Comment: Actually, using my phone ==> `TagLostException` ==> no response at all. Using smartcard reader: if I use my command above ==> `6982`, if I add `00` to the end of the command as suggested by you ==> `6985`